# Can't seem to link to css file in subfolder

Tags: css, iis, coldfusion

I am experiencing and bizarre and frustrating problem. The file structure for my server is as follows:

```
mysite
   _css
      style.css
   index.cfm
   zdevelopment
      _css
          style.css
      index.cfm
```

The issue is that no matter what I do, whether I use relative paths or absolute paths, I can't seem to link successfully to the style.css file in the zdevelopment folder (from the index.cfm within the zdevelopment folder). I can link just fine to the style.css in the _css folder in the main directory. I know it is not linking properly because the stylesheet is listed as not found in Chrome (and Firefox) developer tools. I can include the stylesheet no problem using a cfinclude, but I just can't seem to link to it.

I have tried:

```
_css/style.css
/zdevelopment/_css/style.css
/mysite/zdevelopment/_css/style.css
http://mysite.cfm/zdevelopment/_css/style.css
```

I've tried copying the css file into the same directory as the zdevelopment index.cfm file and just using "style.css". I even let Dreamweaver try to link to it for me. No dice. I am completely stumped.

Edit: 
Followed Mahmoud's suggestion to try checking the file in the browser (hadn't thought of that), and got this error:

```
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

Not sure why that is the case. I can see the file on the server. But I guess it means the issue is not with my linking. Any suggestions for how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: `Any suggestions for how to troubleshoot this?` The first thing I would do is google that error message. (I tried it, and it produced a lot of results, although a lot of red herrings, I admit.)

Comment: Perhaps there is something wrong with the CSS file itself if you cannot browse to it successfully. Try re-saving the CSS file and see if that helps. If not, then try saving a known good CSS file in the same location and see if that one works. The error you received makes me think the file is corrupt or not valid CSS anyway. Can you share the contents of that CSS file?

Comment: what is your development setup?  are you on windows iis, cf built in web server, etc...?  are images showing up ok?

Comment: Ralph: Unfortunately that is the generic Coldfusion server message (error 500). It shows up for everything from syntax errors to problems connecting to the database.

Comment: Miguel: That CSS file was actually directly copied and pasted from one that is working. I also tried deleting everything out of it. No luck.

Comment: Steve: IIS. I don't know much about it though and unfortunately our server guy has stepped out for the moment and I don't know when he'll be back.

Answer (score 1):

1. have you checked it in the browser if its exist or not?
2. have you tired ../

Comment: Just tried #1- put response as an edit in my original post. #2- yes, it gets me to the css file in the main folder.

Comment: is that possible to give us a link?

Comment: The site is password-protected, unfortunately, limited to members of a particular organization.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the issue has been resolved. Some research online revealed that it might have something to do with mimetypes. When our server guy got back I asked him about it, and he mentioned a "wildcard" mimetype that he had added in the last week. He removed the wildcard mimetype, and that solved the issue. Thanks everyone for your help and suggestions!